do not connect extreme points of truncated tikz diagram
Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726538/319072, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724826/319072

I am trying to make a picture where some parts of a point-based plotting mechanism are omitted due to being outside of a specific range.
The problem I am facing is that the extremities of my diagram are being connected by a line.
How can I remove this line, or change its opacity to 0?
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{10}{20}{30}
\draw
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{cos(0)}{sin(0)}{0}}
\ifdim\tdplotresy pt<0.9pt
(\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
\foreach \Vt in {0,5,...,360}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{cos(\Vt)}{sin(\Vt)}{0}}
\ifdim\tdplotresy pt<0.9pt
-- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
\fi
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



To give a sense of what I'm trying to achieve, here is an example of more elaborate code breaking because of this issue:
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}
\newcommand{\SPX}[2]{#1/(1-#2)}
\newcommand{\SPY}[2]{#1/(1-#2)}
\newcommand{\Vr}{5*90/23}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\clip[tdplot_screen_coords] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5);
\draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vr}{\Vr}{\Vr}
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,350}{
    % latitude
    \draw[variable=\Vt,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=100,tdplot_rotated_coords]
    ({\sphereX{0}{\Vn}},{\sphereY{0}{\Vn}},{\sphereZ{0}{\Vn}}) plot ({\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vn}},{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vn}},{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vn}}) -- cycle;
    % stereographic projection of latitude
    \draw
    \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{0}{\Vn}}{\sphereY{0}{\Vn}}{\sphereZ{0}{\Vn}}}
    \ifdim\tdplotresz pt<0.999pt % Exclude points too close to the north pole
    ({\SPX{\tdplotresx}{\tdplotresz}},{\SPY{\tdplotresy}{\tdplotresz}},0)
    \foreach \Vt in {0,5,...,360}{ 
        \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vn}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vn}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vn}}}
        \ifdim\tdplotresz pt<0.999pt % Exclude points too close to the north pole
        -- ({\SPX{\tdplotresx}{\tdplotresz}},{\SPY{\tdplotresy}{\tdplotresz}},0)
        \fi
    };
    
    \else
    (0,0,20)
     \foreach \Vt in {0,5,...,360}{ 
        \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vn}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vn}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vn}}}
        \ifdim\tdplotresz pt<0.999pt % Exclude points too close to the north pole
        -- ({\SPX{\tdplotresx}{\tdplotresz}},{\SPY{\tdplotresy}{\tdplotresz}},0)
        \else
        -- (0,0,20)
        \fi
    };
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


My goal is to fix this gif I'm making, so I can make other ones like it which are more advanced.


In your code, you connect all points within the range, which implies that the two end points of the clipped curve are connected as well. In the code below, the logic is as follows: If the last as well as the current point are visible, then connect them.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \foreach \Vt [
    evaluate=\Vt as \x using cos(\Vt),
    evaluate=\Vt as \y using sin(\Vt),
    remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1.0), % cos(0)
    remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0.0), % sin(0)
  ] in {5,10,...,360}{
    \ifdim \y pt < 0.9pt
      \ifdim \lasty pt < 0.9pt
        \draw (\lastx,\lasty,0) -- (\x,\y,0);
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


